# Parse a XML-formatted String to Java object

Tags: java, xml, parsing, document

I have String that is formatted in XML-format (simplified)

```
<WORKORDER>
    <name>Nils</name>
    <age>25</age>
    <reported>2021-02-04-13.49.05</reported>
</WORKORDER>
```

Now I want to map this to my java (1.8) Object.

```
public class WorkOrder {

    private String name;
    private String age;
    private String reported;
    
   //Getters and setters 
}
```

Here is what I have done:

```
String xml = 

"<WORKORDER>
    <name>Nils</name>
    <age>25</age>
    <reported>2021-02-04-13.49.05</reported>
</WORKORDER>";

WorkOrder workOrder;
workOrder = parseXMLToWorkOrder(xml);


private static WorkOrder parseXMLToWorkOrder(String xml) throws ParserConfigurationException, IOException, SAXException {
        Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
                .newDocumentBuilder()
                .parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));

        NodeList errNodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("error");
        if (errNodes.getLength() > 0) {
            Element err = (Element) errNodes.item(0);
            System.out.println(err.getElementsByTagName("errorMessage")
                    .item(0)
                    .getTextContent());
        } else {
            Element root = doc.getDocumentElement();

            WorkOrder workOrder = new WorkOrder();
            workOrder.setName(doc.getElementsByTagName("name").item(0).getTextContent());
            workOrder.setAge(doc.getElementsByTagName("age").item(0).getTextContent());
            workOrder.setReported(doc.getElementsByTagName("reported").item(0).getTextContent());
            return workOrder;
```

And this works fine. However, the attributes (name/age/reported) can come in any language, so I can't hardcode the `getElementsByTagname`.

I need a way to do this dynamically. The number of attributes are still fixed, but the tag name will be different depending on language. I also get a feeling that this might not be the most efficient way to do this, so any improvement will be appreciated as well!

Comment: You should add a tag for the programming language you're using. It is always necessary to do so when asking code-related questions.

Comment: It is not clear which are the criteria to select elements if the names are not known. Do you want to select them by their index (e.g. first child element is the "name", second the "age"? Then use `root.getElementsByTagName("*")` which gives you a node list of the element nodes you can process (first element has index 0, second index 1).